# Is it possible to send 802.11 data frames manually without monitor mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, 802.11

I am trying to determine whether it is possible to send 802.11 packets manually without first enabling monitor mode on the wireless adapter.

---

Basically, I want to be able send a normal data packet (with the only difference being a spoofed source address) from a computer that does not have a wireless adapter that supports monitor mode.  Ideally the solution exists in either C or Python on a Linux platform.

I can send these data packets when the interface is in monitor mode, such as with this code (I know there's some hand-waving with the `header` variable, but it gets the job done):

```
from scapy.all import Dot11,RadioTap,sendp,hexdump

iface = ''         #Interface name here



header = ('\x60\x98\x00\x00\x0c\x1a\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00')

data = ('\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64')


# create new radiotap frame with raw data
frame = RadioTap()/Dot11(type=2, subtype=8, addr1='ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff',
addr2='22:22:22:22:22:22', addr3='33:33:33:33:33:33')/header/data


frame.show()
print("\nHexdump of frame:")
hexdump(frame)

sendp(frame, iface=iface)
```

However, this code *only* works as long as the interface is in monitor mode.

---

I understand why monitor mode is required for many RadioTap functions such as packet capture where normal destination address filtering needs to be bypassed.  However, I'm struggling to understand why standard data packet transmission is not possible without monitor mode.

Is there a way around this, or is monitor mode always required in order to interface directly with the wireless drivers?

Comment: This is a decent question, but excessively bolding things — as you [did with your initial post](https://superuser.com/posts/1729753/revisions) — is bad form. It seems like you are lecturing the reader on what your issue is when, to be honest, your question is very clear to begin with even without the bolding.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Appreciate the tip - Generally I try to draw attention to exactly what the problem is on a brief scan of the page, sometimes too much so (probably carryover from writing long emails where each question needs to be highlighted).